# Selenium Python - "Glitched" emojis

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, emoji

I'm scraping a website that has a text with both text and emotes.
Emotes are coming like this: `��⚽️⚽️` and then it glitches out due to the `��` part. I've already tried `.replace("�", "")` but that is not working and the string remains unchanged, any ideas?

I want my script to be able to get it done right and then save it on another place, that's why I can't do this manually by myself later